# Prove that for all n>11 we can represent $n$ by $n=3a+7b$

Tags: proof-verification, fake-proofs

So i decided to do this using normal induction.

$P(12)$ true since $12=4 \times 3$

$P(k)=3a+7b$

$P(k+1)=3(a-2)+7(b+1)$

So i think it is proven but i cannot see why we have to assume $n$ is larger than $11$. I mean i know it is impossible for $11$ but lets say $9$.

$P(9)$ true since $9=3 \times 3$

$P(k)=3a+7b$

$P(k+1)=3(a-2)+7(b+1)$.

I am surely missing something but i don't know what ;/

Comment: The induction aspect is actually this: show how to represent $12,13,14$ with $a,b \geq 0,$ which you neglected to mention. Then, every number which can be written as $12 + 3k$ or $13 + 3k$ or $14 + 3k$ can be represented simply by increasing the letter $a.$

Comment: Going from k to k+1 you have to decrease the a in your formulation. But maybe you're missing the assumption that a,b must be nonnegative in the representation.

Comment: @coffeemath well i did so i just have to assume that a>=2 which is equivalent of saiying that P(k) is at minimum 6. isnt it?

Comment: Actually it is possible for 11 = 3(-1) + 7*2.  I think the statement is that a, b are non negative.  it doesn't need to be I guess.  I think a, b being non-zero is somehow more comforting and easier.  After all the is not just true for positive n but negative as well so tradition induction will only work in one direction.  To prove this thouroughly you need induction both up and down.  If we need to arbitrarily choose a starting point, we might as well start at 12 and a, b non-negative.... but you're right.  We don't have to.

Comment: Each time, 2 gets subtracted from a (using only your method). So the more times in a row that idea is applied, the more a decreases, until eventually negative a values arise, not allowed.

Comment: @Sorfosh Not really, if you are using your current induction you need to show $a\geq 2 $ for $P(k)$ implies $a\geq 2$ for $P(k+1)$. $P(k+1)\geq 6$ is not enough to show $a\geq 2$ for $P(k+1)$

Comment: @coffeemath Where are you reading that a and b can't be negative?

Comment: @fleablood I had thought the OP simply did not mention the nonnegative requirement. Argument for this: the Frobenius number is $7\cdot 3 -7-3=11.$ Surely that is not a coincidence... so I thought OP just forgot to mention the nonnegativity constraint in the problem. [Yes, technically OP didn't put it in the question, but I'd bet OP is doing homework or something where that constraint has been made.]

Comment: Yeah the constraints have been made, i am trying to understand why. I did the proof but i cannot see why the constraints are needed

Comment: @Sorfosh If the constraints are not made (so a,b can be negative) then your argument is fine and in fact you could start it at n=1 onwards since 1 is 3*(-2)+7*1.

Comment: @coffeemath but constraints have been made. and i cannot see where in my proof i assume that p(k)>11

Comment: @Sorfosh Another thing: to represent numbers requiring a,b nonnegative is not as easy as with no requirement on them. With the requirement one can get a few small numbers, then cannot get 11, but can get from 12 onwards. This setup is more involved to state than just saying one can get all positive integers (or all integers by using a=b=0 and changing signs as needed).

Comment: Yeah i understand, but either my proof is incorrect or while doing the proof i secretly assumed n>11 and dont see where

Comment: @Sorfosh Your proof is incorrect. Consider the case from $P(14)$ to $P(15)$, $14=3(0)+7(2)$ and using your formula you would get $15=3(-2)+7(3)$ which is not allowed.

Comment: Yeah okay i guess i see it but how do i deal withit

Comment: @Sorfosh So you can see your assumption now, which is not valid as $14$ cannot be expressed as a sum of $6+3x+7y$. To make the $P(14)\implies P(15)$ case work, you simply cannot use your current formula and you need an alternative formula, for example $15=3(0+5)+7(2-2)$.

Comment: got it :) i guess using the minimal counterexample is easier in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your induction concept,

Since we know $3a+7b >10$, we have $a\geq 2$ or $b\geq 2$. Otherwise $a\leq1$ and $b\leq1$ so the sum would be less than or equal to $10$.

(1) If $a\geq 2$ then let $P(k+1)=3(a-2)+7(b+1)$ where $a-2\geq 0$.

(2) If $b\geq 2$ then let $P(k+1)=3(a+5)+7(b-2)$ where $b-2\geq 0$

Comment: i dont really follow.

Comment: i am asking where in my proof i am making the assumption n>11

Comment: The point is you need to generate a non-negative solution for $P(k+1)$. $3(a-2)+7(b+1)$ works only if $a\geq 2$. So for the case where $a\leq 1$ you need to come up with something else, which a possible answer is $3(a+5)+7(b-2)$.

Comment: In your proof, you did not make use of the assumption $n>11$ and that is the reason your proof is incorrect.

Comment: well it should come out during the proof, the assumption i mean.

Comment: Yes, it should come out during the proof, but in your proof you did not use it. It implies $a\geq 2$ or $b\geq 2$ which I used in this answer but there may be other ways of using it as well.

Comment: i see it implies a>=2 but where do i assume b>=2?

Comment: It does not imply $a\geq 2$ but it implies $a\geq 2$ or $b\geq 2$. For example, $14=3(0)+7(2)$ where $a\geq 2$ is not true but still one of them must be at least $2$.

Comment: In your prove each time k goes down by 2.  At 12 a = 4 b=0, at 13 a = 2 b=1 at 14 a = 0 b = 2 and 15 a = -2 b=3.  But this can be avoided by every third increase of k to k + 1 increase a by 5 and decrease by by 2. So 16 a=5 b = 0, 16 a=3 b=1 17 a=1 b=2 18 a=6 b=0, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Provided $a$ and $b$ are non-negative integers, we can write

$$
12 = 3 \times 4 + 7 \times 0
$$
$$
13 = 3 \times 2 + 7 \times 1
$$
$$
14 = 3 \times 0 + 7 \times 2
$$

and then for $n = 15$ and up, we can simply write $n - 3$ in the required form, and then increment $a$ by $1$.

Comment: I am not asking for a solution. I know i can use minimal counterexample. or that p(k)=>p(k+3) and show for k ,k+1 and k+2. But this is not what i am asking for

Comment: Then I think you need to say what you are asking for in a better way than "I am surely missing something but I don't know what." :-) ¶ I don't think you're merely asking why $n > 11$ (because the answer is simply that we can't express $n = 11$ that way), so if you can clarify your question, that would help.

Comment: If you could read the comments below the question, i explain it there.

Comment: Ahh, OK, I see.  But I think you already have what you want then, yes?

Comment: Yup, thanks anyway